# Проверка свойства объекта

Tags: javascript

```
function User() {
    name: prompt("Your full name");
    regDate: new Date();
}
while (User.name != null) {
    arrUsers[i] = new User();
    ...
}
```

Как сделать так, чтобы при нажатии отмены в prompt цикл прекращался?

Comment: А что это за такой интересный синтаксис создания функций. Где про него можно почитать?

Comment: Языком не ошиблись?

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko, а что не так? все нормально.

Comment: @Grundy я не говорю, что не так. Я говорю, что это интересно и где про такое почитать можно.

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko, в ответе ссылка есть.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В данном коде смешались *кони, люди*.

Свойство `name` у функции всегда не `null`, а `User` в данном случае именно функция, а не объект. Следовательно проверка `User.name != null` всегда дает `true` и цикл становится бесконечным.

К самой функции тоже есть претензии: сейчас она делает совсем не то, что от нее ожидается.

В текущем виде внутри функции объявлены две [метки](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/label).

Поэтому при использовании функции в качестве конструктора `new User();` у полученного объекта вместо ожидаемых полей `name` и `regDate` не будет ничего.

Для создания полей их надо присваивать как свойства `this`, например

```
this.name = prompt("Your full name");
```

---

В данном случае лучше вообще вынести вызов `prompt` и конструктора, и передавать в конструктор непосредственно введенное имя.

В этом случае и проверка введенной строки тоже становится тривиальной, например:

```
function User(userName) {
    this.name = userName;
    this.regDate = new Date();
}

...
var userName;
while ((userName = prompt("Your full name")) != null) {
    arrUsers[i] = new User(userName);
    ...
}
```